# How can I copy my entire system from my hard disk to an sd card?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, sd-card

I want to install Arch Linux onto an sd card. Just to clarify, I want keep my entire operating system on it, including all of my files, I do not want it to be in live mode.

I want to copy my entire system from my computer's hard disk to the sd card, including all of my installed packages and configuration files, so that i will not have to redo all of my modifications. How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I would use `rsync`. This will be faster and more efficient than `dd`, can be interrupted, will give you more options and info, can be updated, many benefits. However it is not usually used to copy MBR and other low level stuff that could potentially be important.

Check `man rsync` for your favourite options. It is a comprehensive document.
Alternatively just use my personal favourite which gives a lot more info than you need but soothes my paranoia:

```
rsync -avnu --progress --stats /location-of-system-to-be-copied /place-to-store-the-copy/.
```

This is a dry run command. Remove the `n` to run it live. Probably will require a `sudo` and I like to prepend all that with `time` because it takes so long I leave it and come back and want to know how long it all took.

The above assumes your system isn't running, maybe you are using a liveCD or something. However doing this on a live system is more tricky, you want to use the exclude option on `/proc` and some other stuff, and certainly exclude `/mnt/sdcard` that you are copying to.

Google *rsync live system root* for lots of ideas on how to `rsync` a live system.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `/dev/sda` is your hard disk and `/dev/sdb` is your USB stick using [dd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dd#Disk_cloning_and_restore)

From physical disk `/dev/sda` to physical disk `/dev/sdb`:

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/sdb bs=64K conv=noerror,sync status=progress
```

This will clone the entire drive, including the **MBR** (and therefore bootloader), all **partitions**, **UUIDs**, and **data**.

Comment: Note that it will copy unallocated blocks, too, so might take a lot longer than necessary if you have a large filesystem with only a few files.